# Sharing UUID on Server is Secure?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a query regarding sharing of User's device UUID on a THIRD party server (Analytics service say Google). I am working on sensitive data app & in app there is a requirement to store the device UUID on the server. But I am a little bit serious about the security of the data because User's data security is more important for me.

Is it fine to share user's device UUID with the third party service? If 'NOT' then please suggest me what are the threads in sharing UUID.

Comment: If you yourself are generating the UUIDs then it should be fine.  I don't see what information would be revealed unless you were delivering MAC addresses or something identifying...